# JSON and HTTP POST through URL

Tags: json, jsp, servlets, http-post

How can I allow my servlet to accept 4 parameters via HTTP POST through a URL?

Example of URL: http:///servlet

The information returned will be in text format using the JSON format.

JSONObject myStr = new JSONObject();

Am using Model-View-Controller access model. JSP are my view pages, Servlets are my controllers and model are my data managers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I allow my servlet to accept 4 parameters via HTTP POST through a URL?

Just invoke a HTTP POST request with those 4 parameters.

Either by a simple HTML form.

```
<form action="servletURL" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="param1" value="value1">
    <input type="hidden" name="param2" value="value2">
    <input type="hidden" name="param3" value="value3">
    <input type="hidden" name="param4" value="value4">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Or by Ajax (with little help of [jQuery](http://jquery.com)).

```
<script>
    var params = {
        param1: 'value1',
        param2: 'value2',
        param3: 'value3',
        param4: 'value4'
    };
    $.post('servletURL', params, function(response) {
        alert(response);
    });
</script>
```

Then they'll be available the usual `request.getParameter(name)` way in servlet's `doPost()` method.